# Different variadic arguments passed to templated function depending on the on optimization flag

Tags: c++, templates, g++, clang++

I have a `builder` class that implements a `template <typename M, typename ... Args> register_builder` method.
This method takes a string and a bunch of arguments and passes it to a `const auto& factory = [&]() { return std::make_unique<M>(name, std::forward<Args>(args)...);};` that is used to generate some objects.

Depending on the optimization flag I pass to g++ or clang (14 and 15) this function builds the correct object or not.

With (-std=c++17), the output of the code snippet is correct: `A 0 -3.14`
while with (-std=c++17 -O3) the output is wrong: `A 1000 2.79`

It looks to me like only the last given variadic arguments are taken into account, but I can't see why.

```
#include <string>
#include <functional>
#include <memory>
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

struct iObj{
    using ptr_t = std::unique_ptr<iObj>;

    iObj(const std::string& name, const int& id, const double& x):_name(name), _id(id), _x(x)  {};
    virtual ~iObj(){};

    virtual void run() = 0;

    std::string _name;
    int _id;
    double _x;
};

struct myObj : iObj {
    myObj(const std::string& name, const int& id, const double& x) : iObj(name, id, x) {};
    void run() override {
         std::cout << _name << " " <<_id << " " << _x;
    };
};

struct builder 
{
using factory_t = std::function<iObj::ptr_t()>;

template <typename M, typename ... Args>
void register_builder(const std::string &name, Args &&...args)
{
  if (_factories.find(name) != _factories.end())
    return;

  const auto& factory = [&]() {
    return std::make_unique<M>(name, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  };
  _factories[name] = std::move(factory);
}

iObj::ptr_t build(const std::string& name) const
{
    const auto& it =  _factories.find(name);
    return it->second();
}

std::map<std::string, factory_t> _factories;

};

int main()
{
 builder b;
 b.register_builder<myObj>("A", 0, -3.14);
 b.register_builder<myObj>("B", 1000, 2.79);

 auto obj = b.build("A");
 obj->run();

 return 0;
}
```

This is reproducible on Linux and on [godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/z/eEPK5T6rG) on gcc12.2.

Comment: You capture the arguments by reference in the lambda. By the time you leave the register function they are invalidated.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/8KM6GTjde

Comment: Yeap, the problem was capturing the args. I did try to capture them by value `[=]` but that did not work so I defaulted to by reference, hoping for the best. It seems there is another way, one that seems to fix my issue: `const auto& factory = [name, args = std::make_tuple(std::forward<Args>(args) ...)] () mutable{
        return std::apply([=](auto ... args){
            return std::make_unique<M>(name, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        }, std::move(args));
    };`

Comment: Using `[=]` [works for me](https://godbolt.org/z/a858s9a47) but I had to remove the inner `std::forward` for it to compile. You should also be able to move initialize the captured values to leverage *some* perfect forwarding.

Comment: @mehe *"I did try to capture them by value `[=]` but that did not work"* -- Did not work how? This is probably the question you should have asked, as capturing by value is the answer to the question you did ask.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux @JaMiT when capturing by value [=] it was throwing a compile error at `std::forward<>` as you pointed out. My lack of understanding of the std::forward made me backtrack and default to `[&]`.